# Get shadow root host element

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, shadow-dom

When inserting a script into the shadow root of an element is there a way to refer to the host element?

```
var element = document.createElement('div');
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerHTML = 'console.log(host)'; // << How to get host element??

var shadow = element.createShadowRoot();
shadow.appendChild(script);

document.body.appendChild(element);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9b1vyu4n/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I got this finally figured out.

According to the specification (working draft) a `ShadowRoot` has a read only property called `host`.
http://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/#shadowroot-object

```
interface ShadowRoot : DocumentFragment {
    ...
    readonly    attribute Element        host;
    ...
};
```

You can get to the shadow root by walking up the DOM tree.

```
while(e.nodeType != 11) { // 11 = DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE
    e = e.parentNode;
}
var hostElement = e.host
```

In my case it was simpler since the shadow root was the parent node of the script itself.

```
document.currentScript.parentNode.host
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9b1vyu4n/2/

Comment: "You can get to the shadow root by walking up the DOM tree." , Instead of this use Node.getRootNode(). See Below Answer.

Answer (score 55):

[`Node.getRootNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/getRootNode) was introduced in 2016.

You can now access the host element like so:

```
element.getRootNode().host
```