# In which cases will element.parentElement or element.parentNode be null in a HTML DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, lit-html

I have created custom element using LitHTML and my own bloc based library for state management.
Now I have stumble upon a case where in a element though pretty inside some other elements, returns null for parentNode and parentElement.
I can't figure out why?

[image]

What are cases in which parentNode and parentElement be null ?

Comment: `c` doesn't have a parentElement, but it does have a parentNode which is a shadowRoot. shadowRoots don't have a parentNode property (`c.parentNode.parentNode`) but to access the element that the shadowRoot is attached to you can use `.host` (`c.parentNode.host`). see: [Get shadow root host element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339932/get-shadow-root-host-element), or [ShadowRoot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot)

Comment: @pilchard yes you are correct, please write it as an answer, I will accept it as solution ot the problem.

Comment: Use **getRootNode** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/getRootNode . Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520554/custom-element-getrootnode-closest-function-crossing-multiple-parent-shadowd

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman getRootNode on a normal node will take one directly document node. I traverse through each node and check for propertyat each node as a part of my logic.

Comment: Cool, please add your code so others can learn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element `c` returned by your query has no `parentElement`, but it does have a `parentNode` which is a `shadowRoot`.

ShadowRoots don't have a `parentNode` property (which is why your `c.parentNode.parentNode` call returns `null`) but you can return the element that the `shadowRoot` is attached by accessing the shadowRoots `host` property (`c.parentNode.host`).

See the docs: [ShadowRoot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot)

Or related question: [Get shadow root host element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339932/get-shadow-root-host-element)